# Array.Some cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this Type Error: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')**

The error is coming from this method:

```
private search = (rows: Array<any>) => {
  const columns = rows[0] && Object.keys(rows[0])      
  return rows.filter((row) => 
    columns.some((column : any) => row[column].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1)
  )
}
```

I'm just not sure whats causing it or even how to fix it.

Comment: Evidently row[column] is null, but without the inputs that's all we can say - give a [mre].

Comment: Use row[column]?.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.queryText.toLowerCase())

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because an element of the `row` variable (line 4) is null, so `null.toString()` is not defined. You could fix this issue with another value check:

```
columns.some((column : any) => row[column] && row[column].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```